# Why do the vertical lines of vline not align with the colspec when I set the tblr options using \SetTblrInner?

Tags: tables, tabularray

#### Context

I have a dark coloured table header and white vertical lines in that header. I want to set these options as a default for the `tblr` environment. From the [manual, page 32](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf#page=32) I read that I can do so using the `\SetTblrInner` command. But when I do so, the vertical lines defined in the `colspec` don't align with the vertical lines coloured by `vline`.

#### MWE

This is my starting point:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec = {|l|l|l|},
                row{1} = {bg=blue, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
                hline{1,2,Z} = {},
                vline{2-Y} = {1}{white},
            }
            A & B & C\\
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            10 & 20 & 30\\
            100 & 200 & 300\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I move all options except the `colspec` (as that changes from table to table) into the `\SetTblrInner` command:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrInner{
    row{1} = {bg=blue, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    hline{1,2,Z} = {},
    vline{2-Y} = {1}{white}
}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \begin{tblr}{ colspec = {|l|l|l|} }
            A & B & C\\
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            10 & 20 & 30\\
            100 & 200 & 300\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

And I get this:
[image]

Changing the `vline` color and zooming in, it's visible that the thick white part is not actually the line, but a blank space between the `vline` line and the `|` line:

[image]

#### Question

How can I set default `tblr` options while also using `colspec` in the individual tables?

#### What I've tried

I have removed the intra-column pipe `|` from the `colspec`

```tex
colspec = {|lll|}
```

and set the vertical lines completely in the `\SetTblrInner` part

```tex
\SetTblrInner{
    ...
    vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{black}
}
```

That removes the issue, but reduces flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave also the `|` in the `colspec` you're drawing two vertical lines.
Leave them out and arrange the `vline` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrInner{
    row{1} = {bg=blue, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    hline{1,2,Z} = {},
    vline{1,Z} = {},
    vline{2-Y} = {1}{white},
    vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{},
}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \begin{tblr}{ colspec = {lll} }
            A & B & C\\
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            10 & 20 & 30\\
            100 & 200 & 300\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This in not a workaround, it's a feature of the package.
It allows you to draw how many rules do you like, see this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \begin{tblr}{ colspec = {l|||l|||l} }
            A & B & C\\
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            10 & 20 & 30\\
            100 & 200 & 300\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also an ordinary `tabular` would behave this way.

Comment: Thanks, I edited this workaround briefly after asking the question. I guess my issue is: why are the `|` lines not the same lines as the ones drawn by `vline`?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke It's a feature of the package, you can draw more then one line, see page 16 of the documentation, for example.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke See my renewed answer, hope it explains the reason of this behavior.

Comment: Ok, so the `|` symbol is simply not equal to a `vline`, right? These are just different things and I should not expect them to be usable interchangeably?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke They are the same. You can have more `vline`, too, with the same behavior.

Comment: Ok, so they are the same functionality, but when I define a `vline` *and* a `|` in the `colspec` these refer to two separate vertical lines, not the same vertical line, right? Any way to make them refer to the same vertical line, such that I can define the way a vertical line looks using the `vline` key, but define whether or not a vertical line is shown using the `|` symbol?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Writing `||` is the same as writing `vline{<linenumber>} = {1}{-}{}, vline{<linenumber>} = {2}{-}{}`. Writing `vline` and `|` refers to two separate lines. As far as I know, it's not possibile to "rewrite" the same vertical line. `|` is not an indicator of where the vertical lines should be.